# DLL Process that starts every day on the same time to check files

Tags: c#

I would like to create an "DLL" process that starts every day on 6 P.M. and search for new XML files on a folder path. But i have realy now idea how to realize this.

Is the only way to use a "timer" that starts on the first day on 6 P.M. and have an intervall of 24 h like this ?

```
System.Timers.Timer _myTime = new System.Timers.Timer();



private bool SetTimer(double intervall)
        {
            try
            {
                _myTime.Interval = intervall;
                _myTime.Elapsed += _myTime_Elapsed;
                _myTime.Enabled = true;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    void _myTime_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something to search for new XML files and copy them to a new file or so....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you starting a program with the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Another option would be to use Window's built-in task scheduler and an executable.

Comment: perhaps the windows task scheduler is an option?! It's easy to use and you only have to write a simple c# console application which does the work.

Comment: same idea 3 times  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to implement the scheduling into your programm's logic.
 Simply write and publish your code. Now you can use the Windows **Task Scheduler** in order to implement scheduling. Simply select which programm has to be executed and when.

[This might help.](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)